# How to find the sequence number of an enumerator inside an enumeration?

Tags: c#

Let's assume that there is an enumeration that contains non-ordered by value enumerators. What is the simplest way to find the sequence number of a given enumerator in the enumeration?

Comment: Can you give a bit of an example of what you mean?

Comment: @AlexD You are right.

Comment: what sequence order do you mean? original source order? numerical value order? an example would be really valuable here

Comment: @Marc Gravell I mean the original source order. For example in the example of  AlexD a has sequence number 0 and b 1.

Comment: How would that become even remotely useful? I can't see how breaking such nice abstraction as enums could help.

Comment: @Mephy For example you have some array ot class with operator [] and some enumerator and you need to select the element of the class (or array) that corresponds to the sequence number of the enumerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, basically. This is not supported. The order from `GetNames` and `GetValues` *is* defined, but is based on the *value*. The order from `GetFields` is officially undefined.

Answer (score 0):

if GetFieldsIndex is not officially defined your Might define it unofficially

```
enum MyEnum { a = 5, b = 2, c = 4, d = 1, e = 3 }

public static int GetFieldIndex(this Enum value)
{
  Type t = value.GetType();
  var Fields = t.GetFields();
  Fields = Array.FindAll(Fields, f => f.FieldType.Equals(t));
  var typedFields = Array.ConvertAll(Fields, f => f.GetValue(null));

  return Array.IndexOf(typedFields, value);
}
```

and then consume in the simple way

```
        MyEnum value = MyEnum.d;
        Console.WriteLine(value.GetFieldIndex());
```

Comment: This works for you but not for me. Consider enum { c, b, a, e, d } and now find the sequence number of for example e.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant the following enumeration enum E { a = 5, b = 1, c = 4, d =2, e = 3 }. Now find the sequence number of d.